# I set a proxy server on urllib2, and then I can't change it

Tags: python, proxy, urllib2

Like the title says, my code basically does this:

set proxy, test proxy, do some cool stuff

But after the proxy is set the first time, it sticks that way, never changing. This is the failing code:

```
    # Pick proxy
    r = random.randint(0, len(proxies) - 1)
    proxy = proxies[r]
    print proxy

    # Setup proxy
    l_proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http": "http://{0}:{1}".format(*proxy)})
    l_opener = urllib2.build_opener(l_proxy_support)

    try:
        l_req = l_opener.open(
            urllib2.Request('http://[MYIPADDRESSHERE]/ip.php', None, agent)
        )
        print l_req.read()
    except urllib2.URLError:
        print "Proxy not functioning, aborting..."

    # Do cool stuff here, not really relevant
```

The output ends up being:

```
['X.Y.Z.124', '666', 'http']
[Skarlet] Your IP address is: X.Y.Z.124
['X2.Y2.Z2.190', '666', 'http']
[Skarlet] Your IP address is: X.Y.Z.124
['X3.Y3.Z3.41', '666', 'http']
[Skarlet] Your IP address is: X.Y.Z.124
```

I'm really puzzled right now.

Thanks for your time.

PD: the script that responds from my home IP address is just a PHP echoing $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does seem strange. I've always found the [httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2) module to be the easiest Python HTTP client to work with.  There is an example of using [httplib2 with the socks module](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/wiki/Examples).

Sorry, I know this isn't a specific answer to your question, but it might be a workaround to try.

Comment: You're right, it's not specific, but incredibly helpful.

I have replaced all the urllib2 code with the httplib2 (it wasn't THAT much code to change anyways), and I have reduced the amount of HTTP handling code quite a bit, not to mention httplib2 is much nicer to the eye.

Thanks.

Comment: Just to empathize - urllib and urllib2 drive me up the wall.